# How do I import and access a nested array/object in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, wordpress

I'm working with WordPress blocks using Javascript/React. I have a working piece of code that I want to be able to break up into multiple smaller files for easier management, however I can't seem to figure out how to properly import and access the information I want in this way.

Below I have a const `const BLOCKS_TEMPLATE = [];` with a bunch of data inside it that serves as a template for my custom block. It works fine if I have it inside my main file, but stops working if I take it out and try to import it.

I had tried moving this `BLOCKS_TEMPLATE` const out into its own file `block_template.js` and importing it at the top, then trying to access the data below in `registerBlockType` like below. It's not working for me, and I'm pretty sure I'm just screwing up the syntax. Can someone let me know what I'm doing wrong, if this is possible? Thank you and hopefully this is clear (not sure if the question I wrote is phrased correctly). I'm newer to working with React.

```
import { BLOCKS_TEMPLATE } from "./block_template";
const el = wp.element.createElement;
const { registerBlockType } = wp.blocks;
const { InnerBlocks } = wp.blockEditor;
const { __ } = window.wp.i18n;

registerBlockType('idg-blocks-plugin/stats-bar-template', {
    title: __('Stats Bar Template'),
    category: 'widgets',
    icon: 'welcome-widgets-menus',
    keywords: [__('Statistics'), __('Stats')],
    edit: (props) => {
        return el(
            'div',
            { className: props.className },
            el(InnerBlocks, {
                template: BLOCKS_TEMPLATE,
                templateLock: false,
            })
        );
    },
    save: (props) => {
        return el(
            'div',
            { className: props.className },
            el('div', { className: 'custom-div' }, el(InnerBlocks.Content, {}))
        );
    },
});
```

The external file, `block_template.js`, is set up like this:

```
export const BLOCKS_TEMPLATE = [
    [
        'core/columns',
        {
            className: 'is-style-stats-columns',
        },
        [
            [
                'core/column',
                {
                    className: 'is-statistic',
                },
                [
                    [
                        'core/paragraph',
                        {
                            className: 'is-style-main-stat',
                            placeholder: 'ex: 76.4B',
                            align: 'center',
                        },
                    ],
                    [
                        'core/paragraph',
                        {
                            className: 'is-style-stat-supporting',
                            content: 'ex: Average Buying Power at Each Summit',
                            align: 'center',
                        },
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            [
                'core/column',
                {
                    className: 'is-statistic',
                },
                [
                    [
                        'core/paragraph',
                        {
                            className: 'is-style-main-stat',
                            placeholder: 'ex: 76.4B',
                            align: 'center',
                        },
                    ],
                    [
                        'core/paragraph',
                        {
                            className: 'is-style-stat-supporting',
                            content: 'ex: Average Buying Power at Each Summit',
                            align: 'center',
                        },
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            [
                'core/column',
                {
                    className: 'is-statistic',
                },
                [
                    [
                        'core/paragraph',
                        {
                            className: 'is-style-main-stat',
                            placeholder: 'ex: 76.4B',
                            align: 'center',
                        },
                    ],
                    [
                        'core/paragraph',
                        {
                            className: 'is-style-stat-supporting',
                            content: 'ex: Average Buying Power at Each Summit',
                            align: 'center',
                        },
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
];
```

Comment: what's your error message?

Comment: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`

Reading more about this error, it might not be compiling.

Comment: If you want to import ES6 modules you have to add 'type': 'module' to the package.json as a top level element. // package.json
{
  "type": "module"
}